# I want an EmbeddedListField of comments to show up only when I 'GET' a single post and not when I 'GET' a list of posts

Tags: tastypie, mongoengine, django-nonrel

I have a mongodb document 'Post' which has `EmbeddedListField` of 'comments'. I'm using tastypie to build the API layer and I want the comments to be listed with their body fields only when a single post is requested. When a list of posts is requested I do not want to show the full comment body as this would kill my app's performance. This is what I have in my resource file:

```
comments = tastypie_mongoengine_fields.EmbeddedListField(of='api_core.resources.EmbeddedCommentResource', attribute='comments', full=True, null=True)
```

What can I do about this? I do not want to create two entry points for 'post_entry' and 'post_list' as this would be bad design for the consumer of the APIs.

Answer (score 0):

I did a simple check in the dehydrate method:

```
    def dehydrate(self, bundle):
    if self.get_resource_uri(bundle) != bundle.request.path:
        bundle.data['comments_count'] = len(bundle.data['comments'])
        del bundle.data['comments']
        bundle.data['user_id'] = bundle.data['user'].data['id']
        bundle.data['user_name'] = bundle.data['user'].data['first_name']
        bundle.data['user_uri'] = bundle.data['user'].data['resource_uri']
        del bundle.data['user']
    return bundle
```